# Installation QGIS server on Raspberry

Tags: qgis-server

I'm trying to install QGIS server (LTR) on my Raspberry PI.
I'm following the tutoriel [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu).
But as you can see, when I call for the repository, I have an error:
[image]

Can some one explain me what am I doing wrong?!?

Comment: You are running Rasbian/bullseye version of Linux on your Raspberry and there are no downloads for that.

Comment: I don't understand. On my Raspberry, I have Raspbian (bullseye debian 11). And on qgis.org they mention that there is a distribution for that?!?

Comment: I was reading the error messages (would be better to copy those as text) saying "could not find stuff for Rasbian". I believe the Rasbian is not exactly the same as Debian https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98740/what-is-the-difference-between-raspbian-lite-and-debian and they may need different binaries.

Comment: No, I was able to install qgis server 2.18 last year without a problem… but now I want to update to last LTR!

Comment: In that case I apologize, you know more about the thing than I.

Comment: Not really, I have an error after only 3 command lines 

Comment: Have you tried to use a Debian image from here https://raspi.debian.net/ instead of Rasbian?